# How to get the size of an ImmutableQueue in less than linear time

Tags: c#

I have an *Immutable Queue* declared like this:

```
public ImmutableQueue<JObject> MyImmutableQueue => 
  ImmutableQueue.CreateRange<JObject>(myConcurrentQueue);
```

I want to reference it from my test class like this:

```
myClass.MyImmutableQueue.Count
```

However, I see that the `Count` method does not exist.

I checked the API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467186(v=vs.111).aspx) and there seems to be no method such as `Count`, `Size` or `Length`.

If there is no such method, probably I will make an extension method that iterates and counts the elements, but that's inefficient.

So, is there some method or some (less than linear time complexity) way of counting the elements of an ImmutableQueue?

Comment: "probably I will make an extension method" -- That shouldn't be necessary. The standard [`Enumerable.Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) should work already.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that, because `ImmutableQueue` is implemented in a way that require full traversal to count elements. Even with reflection you cannot do that.

If you look at [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableQueue_1.cs), you will see that internally it uses two `ImmutableStack`s, and `ImmutableStack` is represented with head and tail (where tail is another `ImmutableStack`). So to figure out number of elements you have to count number of elements in those stacks, and to do that - you have to traverse them completely. So count complexity of this implementation of `ImmutableQueue` is always linear.

So if you absolutely need that - just use `IEnumerable.Count()` extension method, because you cannot do any better anyway.

Comment: How on earth would that be impossible?! All operations that you can do on the queue are working on a single element. Regardless of the internal data representation, a count private variable could've been used with every operation either incrementing it or decrementing. This is trivial to do and completely independent of the internal representation. There is no need to traverse the data at all.

Comment: @KornelijePetak using separate mutable variable to track number of items in your immutable queue completely defeats its purpose and so is not an option. Of course it's possible to extend ImmutableQueue with another class, which will carry the count variable (also immutable) but I doubt that's what OP asks about. If you are given _only_ instance of ImmutableQueue - it's not possible to count its elements without traversing whole queue.

Comment: Oh, my appologies. I have completely misunderstood your first sentence. For some reason I thought you were talking theoretically, and you were just stating facts about the actual implementation. I was also a bit careless when reading the OP, hence my comment. You are actually right.